# How should the REST API look for updating a resource with server's datetime?

Tags: database, rest, datetime, server

I am creating a database server with resources with 'lastAccessed' datetime field. This field must be updated with the server's time with every read, but not query. How should I design the REST API if I want to allow clients to update this field at will?

I thought of several options, but none of them seem correct...

1. `GET /api/resources/{resource_id}`

   Even though this is a GET, it updates the 'lastAccessed' field.
2. `PATCH /api/resources/{resource_id}` with `{ lastAccessed: "garbage_value" }`

   Value from the client is ignored and 'lastAccessed' is updated with the server time.
3. `POST /api/resources/{resource_id}/update-last-accessed-time` without payload

   Special endpoint for this purpose agreed on contract
4. `PUT /api/resources/{resource_id}/lastAccessed` without payload

   Intention of this API is to convey that this call will replace the 'lastAccessed' field with the server's default value, in this case, server's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. Doing a `GET` request should typically not influence any meaningful responses.

So I would opt for one of your other three options.

Your `POST` and `PUT` examples are fine, although I don't see a reason for sending "garbage_value" to this endpoint.

You could set a flag like `setLastAccessed: true`. The contents of your `PATCH` body do not need a 1:1 correlation with anything else.

I would likely go with a `POST` on `/api/resources/{resource_id}` or `/api/resources/{resource_id}/update-last-accessed-time` with a specific instruction to update the `lastAccessedTime`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas! Btw, currently the answer seems to have been cut short. Could you fix it please?

Comment: @Efreeto i don;t know what that sentence was leading up to so i just removed it =( happy to answer questions though